# Where have the dompdf documentation and examples gone?

Tags: dompdf

Just come back to use dompdf after some years. It seems everything has changed, and there is no longer any documentation or examples to explain how to use it.

The demo version says that the code is in the tests folder, but that is not longer the case.

Additionally using the quick start in the readme gives a class not found error.

Does anyone actually have this working, or shall I just use a copy of my 3 year old version ?

Thanks
JohnT

Answer (score 0):

The currently-linked demo page is out of date per the current release. The demo is based on code that was included in the [0.6.x release](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/tree/v0.6.2). You can still find the samples in that version of the code under [www/test](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/tree/v0.6.2/www/test).

The same test files can also be rendered under various Dompdf version at https://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php

As for how to get started, the [README.MD](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/README.md) file should give you enough information to get started. There's also additional information in the [wiki](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki).